# DataGridView CheckBox events

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, checkbox

I'm making a `DataGridView` with a series of Checkboxes in it with the same labels horizontally and vertically.  Any labels that are the same, the checkboxes will be inactive, and I only want one of the two "checks" for each combination to be valid.  The following screenshot shows what I have:
[image: DataGridView]

Anything that's checked on the lower half, I want UN-checked on the upper.  So if [quux, spam] (or [7, 8] for zero-based co-ordinates) is checked, I want [spam, quux] ([8, 7]) un-checked.  What I have so far is the following:

```
    dgvSysGrid.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders;
    dgvSysGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
    string[] allsysNames = { "heya", "there", "lots", "of", "names", "foo", "bar", "quux", "spam", "eggs", "bacon" };

    // Add a column for each entry, and a row for each entry, and mark the "diagonals" as readonly
    for (int i = 0; i < allsysNames.Length; i++)
    {
        dgvSysGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(false));
        dgvSysGrid.Columns[i].HeaderText = allsysNames[i];
        dgvSysGrid.Rows.Add();
        dgvSysGrid.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = allsysNames[i];
        // Mark all of the "diagonals" as unable to change
        DataGridViewCell curDiagonal = dgvSysGrid[i, i];
        curDiagonal.ReadOnly = true;
        curDiagonal.Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
        curDiagonal.Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    // Hook up the event handler so that we can change the "corresponding" checkboxes as needed
    //dgvSysGrid.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(dgvSysGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
    dgvSysGrid.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgvSysGrid_CellValueChanged);

}

void dgvSysGrid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Point cur = new Point(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);

    // Change the diagonal checkbox to the opposite state
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell curCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvSysGrid[cur.X, cur.Y];
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell diagCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvSysGrid[cur.Y, cur.X];
    if ((bool)(curCell.Value) == true)
    {
        diagCell.Value = false;
    }
    else
    {
        diagCell.Value = true;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Change the corresponding checkbox to the opposite state of the current one
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void dgvSysGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point cur = dgvSysGrid.CurrentCellAddress;

    // Change the diagonal checkbox to the opposite state
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell curCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvSysGrid[cur.X, cur.Y];
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell diagCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvSysGrid[cur.Y, cur.X];
    if ((bool)(curCell.Value) == true)
    {
        diagCell.Value = false;
    }
    else
    {
        diagCell.Value = true;
    }
}
```

The problem comes is that the cell value changed always seems to be "one behind" where you actually click if I use the `CellValueChanged` event, and I'm not sure how to get the current cell if I'm in the "dirty" state as curCell comes in as a null (suggesting the current cell address is wrong somehow, but I didn't try and get that value out) meaning that path isn't working at all.

Basically, how do I get the "right" address with the right boolean value so that my flipping algorithm will work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ultimately, it was the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event that does it, but you need to do it in the right way.  And the right way is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx)'s, though it doesn't make sense at first glance.

A fragment from above, and what I ultimately did is below:

```
    // Hook up the event handler so that we can change the "corresponding" checkboxes as needed
    dgvSysGrid.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged += new EventHandler(dgvSysGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged);
    dgvSysGrid.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgvSysGrid_CellValueChanged);

}

void dgvSysGrid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Point cur = new Point(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);

    // Change the diagonal checkbox to the opposite state
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell curCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvSysGrid[cur.X, cur.Y];
    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell diagCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvSysGrid[cur.Y, cur.X];
    if ((bool)(curCell.Value) == true)
    {
        diagCell.Value = false;
    }
    else
    {
        diagCell.Value = true;
    }
}

void dgvSysGrid_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvSysGrid.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dgvSysGrid.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Basically, all that's happening is the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event triggers the `CellValueChanged` event, and that's it.  If you just attach the `CellValueChanged` event, then it only triggers AFTER you have left the cell.  I don't know why exactly (considering it's a checkbox, isn't it "done" immediately?), but that's what happens.  And the code as above works, in that the check box changes go in RIGHT away when clicking it.  So it works.

Comment: YES!! ... my search is over ... I can now live happily ever after. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CellValidating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating.aspx) event and the [e.FormattedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellvalidatingeventargs.formattedvalue.aspx) will have the changed value.  If you perform some check, and dont want the value to update, set e.Cancel to true.

Here is the example from the FormattedValue page:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
    int newInteger;

    // Don't try to validate the 'new row' until finished 
    // editing since there
    // is not any point in validating its initial value.
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) { return; }
    if (!int.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(),
        out newInteger) || newInteger < 0)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "the value must be a non-negative integer";
    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work as the `CellValidating` event is only firing when I LEAVE the cell, not when the checkbox is clicked and the state switches.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest technique I've found is:

- register for grid_CellContentClick
- Examine either all rows of the cell using the below, or just the row from the event handler. My code required re-creating a data model from the entire state of the clicked cells.

EditedFormattedValue is the "new" value of the cell, and the value to read.

.

```
var colNumber=0;
foreach (var row in grid.Rows) {
   var dataGridViewCell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)((DataGridViewRow)(row)).Cells[colNumber];
   if (dataGridViewCell.EditedFormattedValue) {
        // This cell is now checked - do whatever you need to with the other cells
   }
}
```