# DataGridView does not update edited value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `CellEndEdit` event on my `DataGridView` that calls a database function to live-update my data. This works fine and my data gets updated in my database. When the data is updated, I call a method called `RefreshRow()` to refresh the data in the `DataGridView`:

```
    private void RefreshRow(int rowIndex) {
        DataGridViewRow row = dgLines.Rows[rowIndex];
        int orderlineid = (int)row.Cells["lineid"].Value;

        DataTable record = Global.DB.GetView("wms_view_line", "lineid="+lineid);

        foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
            DataGridViewColumn col = dgOrderLines.Columns[cell.ColumnIndex];
            string colname = col.Name;

            string newval = record.Rows[0][col.Name].ToString();

            cell.Value = newval;
        }
    }
```

when debugging, I can see `cell.Value = newVal` actually using the new value. However, in my grid, the old value appears again.

Comment: check this solution, maybe helpfull for you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885391/datagridview-checkbox-events

Comment: I was unable to duplicate this behavior - everything worked fine. Is `RefreshRow` called in `CellEndEdit` or somewhere else?